# D3 Sankey diagram using typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I have the code from here https://gist.github.com/d3noob/013054e8d7807dff76247b81b0e29030 working in vanilla javascript, but I am struggling to get a Sankey diagram working in my Angular 2 project (built using Angular CLI) which uses Typescript.

D3 works fine in the project, but even with the the Sankey plugin and typings installed from npm:

Plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-sankey

Typings: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3-sankey

I get errors on:

```
const sankey = d3.sankey()
.nodeWidth(20)
.nodePadding(40)
.size([width, height])

const path = sankey.link()
```

and

```
sankey
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(32)
```

as neither .link() nor .layout() are recognised properties of sankey. Has anyone got a sankey diagram working using Typescript and Angularjs 2+? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't even find `d3.sankey()` after installing the types, how you do that?

Comment: @John_J you need to install the plugin too

Comment: Thank you @Michael ~ btw, I had the sankey chart worked these days, please ref my gist:  https://gist.github.com/MagicJohnJang/3cde82004e632e66b0fc5c156a7c16e9  
.In short: 1. Import d3-sankey with other name than `d3` (which has been used by D3.js).  2.  Define the input (`nodes` and `links`) with specific types (as I show in my gist).

Answer (score 2):

The d3-sankey plugin does not have a link function defined.  You're using code that was meant for an older plugin, not the one that has been rolled into the d3 gitHub repository (d3-sankey).

Try referencing this example instead - it's using the same version of the plugin that you are:  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca9a0bb7ba204d12974bca90acc507c0

Comment: For anyone coming to this question in future, I can confirm the combination of Lecia and John_J's answers do work. I particularly recommend you view John_J's gist in the comments to my original question.